# jmeter Error invoking bsh method: eval Could not initialize class

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to jmeter, and I'm finding it very difficult to solve this error:

> jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Could not initialize class stpl.lib.enc.tea.TEALib

I have added the jar file of the java class in the lib/ext of the jmeter. I'm trying to import the java class in the beanshell preprocessor. The package name is stpl.lib.enc.tea and the class name is TEALib so used the synatx:

```
import stpl.lib.enc.tea.TEALib;    
TEALib t = new TEALib();    
String x = "ABCD";
vars.put("p2",x);
```

Also I have added a dll file in the java class which is also named as TEALib. So sometimes I also get the error saying no TEALib found in class.library.path.

The jmeter throws the two errors above.

Answer (score 1):

First put your jar in jmeter/lib not jmeter/lib/ext.

Second , ensure you fill in :

> -Djava.library.path=